# Only part of the xml gets downloaded on real device android

Tags: android, xml, http-post

I have created a application which download xml from webservice and does some business logic.
I have completed the app and tested successfully on emulator works perfect.

but the problem when i installed on real device running internet using gprs only a part of the xml is getting downloaded every time and so my application doesnot run.

Here is the code login

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String usr;
        String passwd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // // User entered data
            usr = text_username.getText().toString();
            passwd = text_password.getText().toString();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                String xml = getXmlFromUrl(mypref.getNavURL());
                if (xml == null) {

                    return null;
                }
                LoginResponse login = NavizenXmlParserFn.getLoginResponse(xml);
                // Set session
                Session mSession = Session.getSession();
                mSession.setUserId(usr);
                if (login.getStatus().equals(ResponseCodes.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
                    List<WorkCenterResponse> workcenter = NavizenXmlParserFn
                            .getWorkCenterResponse(xml);
                    NavisionApplication app = (NavisionApplication) getApplication();
                    app.setWorkCenterList(workcenter);
                    return ResponseCodes.LOGIN_SUCCESS;
                } else if (login.getStatus()
                        .equals(ResponseCodes.LOGIN_FAILURE)) {
                    return ResponseCodes.LOGIN_FAILURE;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogTofile.writeException(e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            showToast(response);
            pd_login.dismiss();
            // if (validateLocally().equals(ResponseCodes.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
            // Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SelectCenter.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
            // } else {
            // showDialogOk("Error", "Invalid username or password");
            // }
            if (result == null) {
                showDialogOk("Unable to connect", "Try Again later");
//              Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SelectCenter.class);
//              startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
            if (result.equals(ResponseCodes.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SelectCenter.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                showDialogOk("Error", "Invalid username or password");
            }

        }
        String response;
        public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {

            try {
                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                loginRequest.mPassword = passwd;
                loginRequest.mRequestDate = DateUtility.getDate();// "06-20-2011";
                loginRequest.mRequestEntity = "Login";
                loginRequest.mRequestID = Constants.mRequestID;
                loginRequest.mRequestTime = DateUtility.getTime();// "19:03:22";
                loginRequest.mRequestType = "New";
                loginRequest.mTransactionID = Constants.mTransactionID;
                loginRequest.mUserID = usr;

                final String xml = NavizenXmlParserFn
                        .getRequestxml(loginRequest);
                Log.i("LoginRequest", xml);

                response = NavConnection.connection(url,
                        xml, mypref.getNavUserId(), mypref.getNavPassword());
                LogTofile.writeString("Login Response: \n"+response);
                Log.i("LoginrResponse", response); //when only part of the xml gets printed


                return response;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogTofile.writeException(e);
                return null;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogTofile.writeException(e);
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogTofile.writeException(e);
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogTofile.writeException(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }

    }
```

And this the part of the xml

[image]

Here is the code for connection

```
public static String connection(String url, String xml, String id,
        String pass) {
    String xml2 ;
    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeConnectionOut = 60000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeConnectionOut);
        int timeoutSocket = 60000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        Log.i("url passon server", " " + url);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml, HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reqxml", xml));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u_password", pass));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        xml2 = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        //Log.e("Connection  Response:", xml2);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //showToast(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("Connection  :", "UnsupportedEncodingException exception : "
                + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //showToast(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("Connection :",
                "ClientProtocolException exception : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //showToast(e.getMessage());
        LogTofile.writeException(e);
        Log.e("Connection :", "IOException exception : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //showToast(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("Connection :",
                "RuntimeException exception : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return xml2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and print logs and see if your connection doesn't get broken in between? It seems that the core code of your application that fetches the data from the server is in the line:

```
   response = NavConnection.connection(url, xml, mypref.getNavUserId(), mypref.getNavPassword());
```

So you will have to print some log statements in that class and see what is happening. Try to play around with some connection parameters etc.

Comment: I have updated my connection code.... and xml file which need to be downloaded is only 2KB in size.... I think connection breakup issue will be fixed by http class... and should through some exception .... but in my case part of the file is getting is the confusion

Comment: Are you always getting this part of the xml? Or you receive a broken xml of different size each time.

Comment: Hi @Sumeet Khullar I checked my applicaiton on 3g internet connection on mobile .... it worked successfully.... the actual problem was my 2g data connection